# Pgfkeys: obtaining a list of defined (sub)keys

Tags: pgfkeys

I would like to understand if `pgfkeys` already offers a way (although undocumented, as far as I could see) to obtain a list of defined keys in a path, that is

```
\pgfkeys{
    /my/path/a = 1,
    /my/path/b/c = x,
}
\pgfkeysdefinedat{/my/path}{\thekeyslist} % missing macro
\thekeyslist      -> {a,b/c} % also acceptable with full path
% also acceptable -> {a,b}
```

(Ideally this would be packaged into a handler `/.ls=\macro`)

If this is not supported, I would like to know what's an idiomatic way of defining an handler that explicitly accumulates key names:

```
\pgfkeys{
    /my/path/a/.track={code of key a},
    /my/path/b/.track={code of key b},
    /my/path/.ls/.get=\thekeyslist,
}
\thekeyslist -> {a,b}
```

Where `/.track={code}` is equivalent to `/.code={code}` but with the side-effect of accumulating the key name into `/.ls`.

Otherwise, as last resort,

```
\pgfkeys{
    /my/path/a/.track={\thekeyslist}{code of key a},
    /my/path/b/.track={\thekeyslist}{code of key b},
}
\thekeyslist -> {/my/path/a,/my/path/b}
```

Answer (score 1):

[MarmotGhost](https://github.com/marmotghost) has developed an [experimental package](https://github.com/marmotghost/pgf-pathology) for a question on [topanswers.xyz/tex](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1483#a1724) which can track the usage of, say, the `.code` handler.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pathology}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\pgfkeys{install tracking for={.code}}
\pgfkeys{
  /my/path/a/.code = #1,
  /my/path/b/c/.code = #1
}
\begin{document}
\FolderForestContent{/my/path/}
\bracketset{action character=@}
\begin{forest} for tree={grow'=0,folder}
@\ForestContent
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]